# SQL insertion fail, no error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this problem with a simple sql insertion for creating a topic in a forum, by entering the name and selecting the category. I can't figure out why it doesn't work while I use the same thing to create categories and it works fine, and I don't receive any error message, so here are my files:

postTopic.php , page from where I choose name and category for the topic:

```
<form method="post" action="addTopic.php">
    <input type="text" name="topic_subject"  placeholder="Nom du topic"/><br />
    <span id="catC">Choisissez la catégorie: </span><br />
    <select name="topic_cat"><?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_name;";
    $statement = $dbh->query($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    foreach ($statement as $row){
        echo "<option>". $row['cat_name'].$row['cat_id']."</option>";
    }

    ?></select><br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Valider la création du topic" />
```

addTopic.php for treatment of the form:

```
if ($_POST['topic_subject'] != "")
{
   $idc = $_POST['topic_cat'];
   $idc = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $idc); //exctract the category id
   $topictitle= $_POST['topic_subject'];

   $sql= "INSERT INTO topics (topic_subject, topic_cat) VALUES (:sujet, :cat);";
   $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $statement->bindParam(':sujet', $topictitle);
   $statement->bindParam(':cat', $idc);
   $statement->execute();
   //echo $topictitle;
   //echo $idc;
```

So I have no problem getting the good values for `$topictitle` and `$idc` but it fails to insert?

Comment: You're in Silent Errors mode (the default, stupidly). Turn Exception mode on.

Comment: Also, check your web server's `error.log` file.

Comment: Your options have no `value`. So `topic_cat` is empty.

Comment: You dont' set any value to your input element topic_subject. Add a value or check with isset() instead in your php code

Comment: Thanks Niet The Dark, i've set to exception mode on and now i see it's a problem with my database  about "Integrity constraint violation:" i'll check this